# Entity Framework 0..1 to 0 relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

```
class First
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Second
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? First_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("First_Id")]
    public First First { get; set; }
}

public class SecondMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Second>
{
    public SecondMapping () 
        : base()
    {
        this.HasOptional(s => s.First)
            .With ... ???
    }
}
```

Second may have a reference to First. But First never has a reference to Second. Is it possible to apply this mapping with Entity Framework 4.1?

**EDIT:**
Previously, that was my solution:

```
this.HasOptional(s => s.First)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Second could contain one instance of First (dependent on some kind of Usage-Attribute). First doesn't contain any instance of Second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One-to-one relation is possible only if foreign key is also primary key of dependent entity. So  the correct mapping is:

```
class First
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Second
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("First")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public First First { get; set; }
}
```

The reason is that to enforce one-to-one relation in the database foreign key must be unique in the `Second` entity. But entity framework doesn't support unique keys - the only unique value for EF is primary key. This is limitation of EF.

There is workaround described on [Morteza Manavi's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx). Workaround is based on mapping association as one-to-many and enforcing uniqueness in database by introducing unique constraints in custom database initializer.

Comment: Spoken in EF language: Shouldn't it be a optional:optional relation without a navigation property on the other side of the relation?

Comment: It cannot be optional optional once you place FK on PK - PK must be defined and because of that principal entity with the same PK value is required.

Comment: I've edited my post to describe my issue in more detail. Please take note.

Comment: I checked your previous code and it creates one-to-many relation

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - Is there any way you know of to do this "hack" in a DatabaseFirst approach?  Or is it only possible with fluent mappings?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to achieve a 1-to-1 relationship, where there is at the most only one `Second` entity associated to a `First` entity, and where there is no reverse property try the following:

```
class First
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FirstId { get; set; }
}

class Second
{
    [Key]
    public Guid FirstId { get; set; }
    public First First { get; set; }
}

class SecondMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Second>
{
    public SecondMapping()
    {
        this.HasRequired(s => s.First);
    }
}
```

You can however use a separate `First_id` column to do this kind of association, but then you would be effectively creating a 1-to-N relationship. It can be 'forced' to be 1-to-1 via a UNIQUE constraint, but you won't be able to create a reverse property due to a limitation in EF (as Ladislav mentioned):

```
class SecondMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Second>
{
    public SecondMapping()
    {
        this.HasRequired(s => s.First).WithMany().HasForeignKey("First_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take note of my comment at Ladislav Mrnkas answer above.