# Breeze.js : how to store an entity relation using the OData adapter

Tags: odata, breeze, jaydata

My goal is to persist a simple relationship between two breeze entities on my OData server.

I've setup a server, I am able to:

- insert data
- query data
- create a relation between two entities client-side
- **BUT** not able to persist the relationship server-side.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Below is my setup details

---

- I'm using OData/MongoDB backend running [JayData](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-set-up-a-nodejs-odata-endpoint-with-odata-server) on Node.js (virtualBox, ubuntu 12.04, node.js, MongoDB)
- I have created a simple data model with a user and a person entity based on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370922/creating-updating-breeze-entities-with-one-to-one-relationship/16453126#16453126). This is the JayData datamodel definition

>

```
$data.Class.define("$org.Types.user", $data.Entity, null, {
    Id: {type: "id", key: true, computed: true, nullable: false },
    Person: { type: "$org.Types.person", inverseProperty: "User", required:true },
    EmailAddress: { type: "string"},
    Password: { type: "string"}
}, null)

$data.Class.define("$org.Types.person", $data.Entity, null, {
    Id: {type: "id", key: true, computed: true, nullable: false },
    User: { type: "$org.Types.user", inverseProperty: "Person"},
    FirstName: { type: "string"},
    LastName: { type: "string"}
}, null);


$data.Class.defineEx("$org.Types.Context", [$data.EntityContext, $data.ServiceBase], null, {
    User: {type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.Types.user } ,
    Person: {type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.Types.person }
});

exports = $org.Types.Context;
```

- I'm able to query the data using Breeze.js
- I'm able to insert User and Person entities using Breeze.js
- I'm able to set a relation in Breeze and I see the changes to the entities
- I've updated Breeze.js to 1.3.3

>

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('api/');
// other breeze initialization stuff, metadata etc.

var person = manager.createEntity('Person', undefined, breeze.EntityState.Detached);
var user = manager.createEntity('User', undefined, breeze.EntityState.Detached);

// set other fields, name, email, password
user.Person(user);
manager.addEntity(user);
manager.addEntity(person);

// save the changes
manager.saveChanges().then(function() { // etc
```

But I only see two OData post for the two entities but nothing to tie the two entities together

- I ruled out the OData adapter as both the WebAPI and OData adapter call the same functions in the Breeze code base and there are multiple Breeze/WebAPI that demonstrate the ability to query and inserted related entities.
- I haven't seen a Breeze.js / OData sample that seems to address this.
- The closest example that works is a [datajs code sample](http://datajs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Linked%20Data%20Sample&referringTitle=Documentation). It posts the related entity to /$links/ to create the relationship (something I don't see in the OData adapter of neither Breeze.js or JayData).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Breeze with JayData server, but I've been using [JayData client library](http://jaydata.org) to save data over OData for a year and it works with static schema (you generate it with JaySvcUtil) and dynamic schema (grabs the metadata from the server in runtime) as well.ű

To important things:

- use typed entites, not POCO objects
- set the required side of the relationship to have the items persisted

  ```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://include.jaydata.org/datajs-1.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
  <script>
          var url = 'http://localhost:54001/personService';

          $data.service(url, function(contextFactory, contextType){
              var db = contextFactory();
              db.onReady(function(){

                  var user = new db.User.elementType({ EmailAddress: 'joe.smith@company.org'});
                  var person = new db.Person.elementType({ FistName: 'Joe', LastName: 'Smith', User: user }); //set the value to the required side of the relationship to have your entities saved in the batch
                  db.Person.add(person)

                  db.saveChanges(function () {
                      db.Person.include('User').toArray(function (p) { console.log(p);});
                  });
              })
          });
  ```

disclaimer: I'm member of the JayData dev team, so you can help you with the server-side, too.

Comment: Thanks the code worked and sent out the expected value. Though I get an error on the server side when trying to save the Person I get the following "TypeError: Object #<Object< has no method 'getType'.

Comment: It works when using the new [odata-server npm module](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-set-up-a-nodejs-odata-endpoint-with-odata-server). Thanks for your help.