# Entity Framework 0:1 relationship isn't being mapped

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model of Job that I'm trying to add an optional job survey to:

```
public class Job
{

    [Key]
    public int JobID { get; set; }

    // Leaving out all the other fields...

    public virtual JobSurvey JobSurvey { get; set; }

}
```

The job survey model looks like this:

```
public class JobSurvey
{
    [Key]
    public int JobSurveyId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? SentDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? ReturnedDate { get; set; }

    public int? RatingValue { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

In my context I've added the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.JobSurvey)
            .WithRequired(j => j.Job);
```

When I ran add-migration, the script created the following:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.JobSurveys",
    c => new
        {
            JobSurveyId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            CustomerEmail = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
            SentDate = c.DateTime(storeType: "date"),
            RatingValue = c.Int(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.JobSurveyId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Jobs", t => t.JobSurveyId)
```

My problem is that the table that was created, has no foreign key property to be able to go to the related entity.

So in my SQL, there is no JobSurveyId property that lets me get the survey for a job, and my JobSurvey table doesn't have a navigation property going back to the Job.  So I can create JobSurveys, but they're not linked.

What have I done wrong?

**Edit**

I've tried modifying JobSurvey as follows:

```
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Job")]
    public int JobSurveyId { get; set; }

    public int JobId { get; set; }
```

no success

**Edit 2**

Have also tried adding [Required] to the navigation property, but add-migration isn't picking up this as a change that needs updating:

```
    [Required]
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
```

Comment: İ think you have not correctly showed your `Job` class. You initialize context inside model? declared proeprty inside constructor?

Comment: No, I'm not initialising the jobsurvey property in the Job constructor (as JobSurvey can be null)

Comment: please correct your `Job` class in the question

Comment: What's wrong with my job class?  What correction? You have all the properties there that are relevant?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean, I updated the question

Comment: Check out this: [How Should I Declare Foreign Key Relationships Using Code First Entity Framework (4.1) in MVC3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542864/how-should-i-declare-foreign-key-relationships-using-code-first-entity-framework#5543702), basically you can set the foreign key explicitly, as one of the answers there states.

Comment: @Evonet, so you should check your question before adding comment.

Comment: In one-to-one relationships, PK is also FK

Comment: I've updated my question, the link that @KeyurPATEL provided didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *one-to-one* or *one-to-zero or one* relationships *priamry key* in the dependent model is also *foreign key* to parent model. There is no need for additional *foreign key* because there can only be one data linked to parent, it is reasonable to link them with thier IDs. So in your case `JobSurveyId` inside `JobSurvey` model is also foreign key to `Job`.

```
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    public int JobID { get; set; }

    public virtual JobSurvey JobSurvey { get; set; }
}

public class JobSurvey
{
    [Key]
    public int JobSurveyId { get; set; } // This is also foreign key to Job

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

Be sure to check [this site](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1to1/) out.

Comment: Yes, you are serching for foreing key and I try to explain you that `JobSurveyId` is foreign key

Comment: In my database, there is no property in JobSurvey that references the job

Comment: I do not know about your database, but in migrations file it is clearly noted: `.ForeignKey("dbo.Jobs", t => t.JobSurveyId)`

Answer (score 1):

Since I would have to write a lot in the comment, try this, its according to the link I replied but I don't think you followed it right:

```
public class JobSurvey
{
    [Key]
    public int JobSurveyId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? SentDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? ReturnedDate { get; set; }

    public int? RatingValue { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Job")]
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**
I'm not entirely sure whether you want 0:1 or 1:1 so here are all the possibilities (in links):

**1:1**

[Entity Framework 1 to 1 relationship using code first. how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724964/entity-framework-1-to-1-relationship-using-code-first-how)

[EF Code-First One-to-one relationship: Multiplicity is not valid in Role * in relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389707/ef-code-first-one-to-one-relationship-multiplicity-is-not-valid-in-role-in-re)

**0:1**

[Is it possible to capture a 0..1 to 0..1 relationship in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889367/is-it-possible-to-capture-a-0-1-to-0-1-relationship-in-entity-framework)

[Entity Framework 0..1 to 0 relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980260/entity-framework-0-1-to-0-relation)

Basically this could be your solution:

```
public class JobSurvey
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("First")]
    public int JobSurveyId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? SentDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? ReturnedDate { get; set; }

    public int? RatingValue { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Trying this way, I get the following error when adding a migration:  One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

JobSurvey_Job_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'JobSurvey_Job_Source' in relationship 'JobSurvey_Job'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: In *one-to-one* relationships there is no need to additional foreign key.

Comment: Do I also need the fluent API entry?

Answer (score 0):

you job class is okay, you only have to add ForeignKey attribute to your JobSurvey to the correct id property:

```
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    public int JobID { get; set; }

    public virtual JobSurvey JobSurvey { get; set; }
}

public class JobSurvey
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Job")]
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }

    /* other properties */
}
```